# PHP string and number to an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, numbers, explode

I have php var with multiple string values and numbers,

```
$string = 'Simple 12, Complex 16';
```

i explode this to an array, but i need to explode this string to be like below array.

```
Array(
   [0] => Array(
      [Simple] => 12,
      [Complex] => 16
   )
)
```

what is the perfect way to do this in php?

Comment: Is it always [One Word] [Number], [One Word] [Number]?

Comment: It's simple task. Where is your effort for solving this problem?

Comment: i can explode this to an array like Array( [0] => 'Simple 12', 'Complex 16' ) but i dont know how to do the next level: extracting number and string separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way:

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+)\s*(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$string = 'Simple 12, Complex 16';
$values=explode(",",$string);
$result=array();
foreach($values as $value)
{
  $value=trim($value);
  list($type,$count)=explode(" ",$value);
  $result[0][$type]=$count;
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Simple] => 12
            [Complex] => 16
        )

)
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/OH3AAGHy)

Comment: thanks, but what if that string got string and number without space like > 'Complex16' ?, thanks again.

Comment: That's another story then, Will `Complex` be always same word?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this, if you want to get out put like this.

```
 <?PHP
    $string = 'Simple 12, Complex 16';
    $my_arr1 = explode(',',$string);
    foreach ($my_arr1 as $value) {
        $value=trim($value);
        $my_arr2 = explode(' ',$value);
        $final_array[$my_arr2[0]]=$my_arr2[1];
    }
    print_r($final_array);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [Simple] => 12
    [Complex] => 16
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
preg_match_all("/[A-Za-z]+/","Simple 12, Complex 16",$keys);
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{2}/","Simple 12, Complex 16",$vals);
$a = array_combine($keys[0],$vals[0]);
print_r($a);
```

try it out

Answer (score 0):

The reply from user "Ø Hanky Panky Ø", have an error:

**Here:**

```
$result[0][$type]=$count;
```

**Correctly is:**

```
$result[][$type]=$count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+)\s*(\d+)/', $string, $matc);

$output = array_combine($match[1], $match[2]);
```